# Open Dev Menu or reload app without shaking?

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to open dev menu or reload app without shaking the app?

Android
Wireless over wifi so no usb cable
Windows 10

Hot reload or Live reload is not good enough and my arm hurts :)

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html is pretty clear about the short cut keys

Comment: @bennygenel for emulator yes but I use a physical device

Answer (score 25):

for android :
in your package.json add following lines in scripts

```
 "reload":"adb shell input keyevent 82 && adb shell input keyevent 66 && adb shell input keyevent 66",
 "devmenu":"adb shell input keyevent 82",
 "debug":"adb shell input keyevent 82 && adb shell input keyevent 61 && adb shell input keyevent 66 && adb shell input keyevent 66"
```

now you can run `npm run devmenu` to open shake menu in android,
and  `reload` to reload the app, and `debug` to connect to remote debugger.

for ios : you can make a button for it somewhere in app, and let this thing only be shown when app is in dev mode.

```
import {NativeModules,Platform} from "react-native"


renderDevMenuTouchable = () => {
    if(__DEV__ && Platform.OS == "ios" ){
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.touchableDebug}
            onPress={()=>{
                NativeModules.DevMenu.reload();
            }}
            onLongPress={()=>{
                NativeModules.DevMenu.show();
            }}
            > 
            <View style={{backgroundColor:"red",width:23,height:25}}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: `devmenu` works nicely here.  However, a reload with these options will show `"adb server is out of date.  killing..."` .  At the next reload, the phone displays a RedBox message with  `Could not connect to development server `.   In my `react-native run-android` output, I see at the end `adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (41); killing...` so perhaps those two are conflicting.

Comment: why `NativeModules.DevMenu` returns `null`  on Android?

Answer (score 12):

As @bennygenel hints, from that page you can see there is a command on Android through adb

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

to open menu on wireless devices

Comment: Working at the moment on trying to get adb to work wireless not successfull

Comment: (addendum/caveat with my upvote - my device is connected via USB, which isn't available in the body of the question, although it does solve the question as stated in the title...)

Answer (score 11):

I have added `Shake` gesture to `Assistive Touch` menu, and this works okay for me.[image]

Comment: Helpful answer.

Comment: Nickname checks out

Comment: Lovely! Thanks @Lazy!
To add to this (and make it even more lazier), you can edit the icons in the assistive touch menu and remove all except for the Shake.
This will make the phone receive a Shake when you press the assistive touch!

Answer (score 7):

You can configure long pressing the Android system `Recent` button to **Open/close menu**

This would open the dev menu in a react native app.

[image]

Comment: Exact answer for Android, if trying to open menu without being physically connected to send an adb command.

Answer (score 6):

You can send a reload call to the device with: `adb shell input keyboard text "rr"`

Comment: but how to send `CMD + M` to open the menu?

Comment: for me only using key code worked `adb shell input keyevent 82`

Comment: While I'm running the app, I just opened a new terminal and ran this command. Nice one

Answer (score 1):

For iOS I like to wrap my app in a component like this which allows a 3 finger touch to trigger the dev menu:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

// wraps the app in a function to allow three finger dev menu access
const DevMenuTrigger = ({ children }) => {
  const { DevMenu } = NativeModules;
  const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
      if (gestureState.numberActiveTouches === 3) {
        DevMenu.show();
      }
    },
  });
  return <View style={{ flex: 1 }} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>{children}</View>;
};

const DevApp = () => (<DevMenuTrigger><App /></DevMenuTrigger>);

// export default App;
export default DevApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me only using `adb shell input keyevent 82` worked

for convenience you can add it to your `scripts` inside the `package.json` file

something link this:
`"android-menu": "adb shell input keyevent 82"`

also apparently there is an issue with KK devices - [solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609855/adb-key-event-82-for-unlocking-the-android-device-screen-is-not-working-for-kk-d)

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to open Debug menu by volume keys in Android. Check the below link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59526945/958913

Answer (score 0):

Not applicable for `adb shell input keyevent 82`.

When you start the service, a prompt will be printed in the terminal.

`"start": "react-native start",`

Press `d`

```
      Welcome to Metro!
Fast - Scalable - Integrated

To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is by:

```
typing "d" in the terminal where you're running the Metro server (basically the terminal where you've typed in "yarn/ npm start"
```

Answer (score 0):

Flipper has a button for it on the top left:

[image: Flipper Reload App Button]